# Retrieving Id's from nested layouts

Tags: android, fragment, scrollview, android-relativelayout, findviewbyid

My problem is this, I have multiple RelativeLayouts in a LinearLayout inside of a ScrollView that is in the main RelativeLayout. When trying to obtain the id's in the fragment class I have it keeps giving me errors.

I've looked around for an answer for this for about 2 days now and have only come across an idea of using

```
<include name="some_name" layout="@layout/some_layout"/>
```

and it doesn't really help me with my app. I'm trying to develop a calendar week view which I already have the numbers working and the time on the left.

Here is my xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/day_labels_linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <!-- not important but this holds the numbers up top -->
    </LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/calendar_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/day_labels_linear_layout"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:scrollbars = "none">

        <!-- used to space each day with the day_labels_linear_layout weights -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/calendar_spacer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <!--This has all of the hours, I just didn't include them
                because it would take up so much room-->
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/hours_relative_layout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2.5"
                android:background="@color/scheduler_background" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time_12_am"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:paddingBottom="25dp"
                    android:paddingTop="25dp"
                    android:text="@string/text_time_12_am" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time_1_am"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/time_12_am"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:paddingBottom="25dp"
                    android:paddingTop="25dp"
                    android:text="@string/text_time_1_am" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time_2_am"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/time_1_am"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:paddingBottom="25dp"
                    android:paddingTop="25dp"
                    android:text="@string/text_time_2_am" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/sunday_relative_layout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2" >

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/divider_sunday_left"
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:background="@color/divider_scheduler" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/sunday_day"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@color/transparent" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/divider_sunday_right"
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:background="@color/divider_scheduler" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <!-- there is a Relative layout for each day-->

        </LinearLayout>          
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

So when I try to access the id's this is what I get:

```
RelativeLayout sundayRL;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scheduler, null);

    sundayRL = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sunday_relative_layout);


}
```

It gives me the error: sunday_relative_layout cannot be resolved or is not a field, I added a button to see if I could get the id for that and the same result happened. Yet I was able to find the id's for each of the day numbers and day names that is in the top LinearLayout.

Does anyone have a better solution to this? I'm trying to register when the user clicks the view so I can send them to a scheduling page.

EDIT:
So changing null to container allowed me to find my Ids

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scheduler, container);
```

But it caused another issue with a map fragment on one of the other fragments saying I didn't have the right API key which it does.

Comment: Just checking, Is the layout code you posted of `fragment_scheduler`?

Comment: Yes, thats my xml file

Comment: Why don't you use a GridView for showing items of the same type?

Comment: What happens if you use `inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scheduler, container)` ?

Comment: I was having trouble trying to figure out how I could line up the blocks for each day of the week with its respective column in the number linear layout section. So I used another LinearLayout using the weights to space them the same.

Comment: That worked! adding inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scheduler, container) fixed it.

Comment: @MatthewCollins Glad it helped. Post it as answer instead of editing the question and mark it resolved.

Comment: Why should it matter that you specified container as the parent view for the sake of retrieving your child view with id R.id.sunday_relative_layout?  I'm not seeing how this fixed the problem.  Are you sure you don't have multiple fragment_scheduler.xml files in different layout dpi folders?

Comment: fragment_scheduler is the only xml file, It actually did allow me to find an id, how I'm not sure, but it then caused the app to crash, which gave me a google map key error which I don't get when it is set to null.

Answer (score 0):

If you have nested layouts
eg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout >
    <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/rl2>
         <Button
           android:id="@+id/getStarted"
            />
   </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And you want to press a button in the nested one.
Add ID on the nested Layout.

and use this code in onCreate()

```
View view = (View) findViewById(R.id.rl2);
Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.getStarted);
```